# Ошибка в методе при использовании @NotNull

Tags: java, валидация, ejb

`EJB 3.2 + GlassFish`.
При запуске приложения выскакивает ошибка:

> 2017-05-08 10:56:55,831] Artifact mvnApp:war exploded:
>   java.io.IOException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred
>   during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI definition
>   failure:HV000151: A method overriding another method must not alter
>   the parameter constraint configuration, but method public ru.Book
>   ru.BookEJB.createBook(ru.Book) changes the configuration of public
>   abstract ru.Book ru.BookEJBRemote.createBook(ru.Book).. Please see
>   server.log for more details.

Ругается на `@NotNull` в методе:

```
public Book createBook(@NotNull Book book) {
        em.persist(book);
        return book;
    }
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Судя по сообщению ("A method overriding another method must not alter the parameter constraint configuration") метод `createBook` определён в каком-то родительском классе, причём без `@NotNull`, а тут вы его перезаписываете и добавляете `@NotNull`. Это нарушает [принцип подстановки Лисков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2), и, вероятно, поэтому запрещено.

Comment: В этом и была проблема!)